# "Практически" и "теоретически" - значения

Tags: семантика

Как понимать значение этих слов, когда они противопоставляются вне научного контекста? Раньше с этими понятиями СМИ все время путались, потом, вроде, пришли к какому-то общему знаменателю. А сейчас опять вводят меня в ступор.

Вот такая, к примеру, фраза:
*"Теоретически дом уже построен, а практически до этого еще далеко"*.
Или:
*"Теоретически он уже стал обладателем кубка, а практически ему еще предстоит это доказать на последнем соревновании"*.
Или совсем уже на бытовом уровне:
*"Теоретически ты прав, а практически - все может быть"*.
Как это все понимать? Может ли такое быть?

Comment: Ирина, почему "или" с большой буквы, а "кубок" с маленькой?

Comment: Потому, что перед "Или" у меня точка. А "кубок" - нарицательное. Не вижу причин для заглавной.

Comment: Перед "или" в конце примера как раз у Вас нету точки! А "кубок" в данном контексте означает "Кубок мира", разве нет? А он всегда пишется с большой буквы.

Comment: Точка уже есть. А про кубок - понятия не имею, пример условный. А хоть бы и мира, почему кубок-то с заглавной?!

Comment: http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4630 Вот тут про это нашёл. "Кубок мира" — это серия гонок или других видов соревнований (в других видах спорта), длящихся в районе полугода, а может и года. В лыжнах гонках, биатлоне, например, и не только разыгрываются БХГ (большие хрустальные глобусы). Ну и вообще это престижно очень стать обладателем КМ. Поскольку это серия состязаний, а не кубок как сосуд, то пишется с большой буквы.

Comment: Я не хочу это обсуждать. смысл моего вопроса не в том, что такое "Кубок мира". Можете открыть отдельную тему. Я писала и буду писать "кубок" со строчной, если в тексте это просто "кубок".

Comment: Да не буду я открывать. Я знаю, что так правильно. А Вы, если Вам так хочется, оставьте так, раз Вам так нравится. Я считаю, что Вы имеете на это право, всё-таки случай не вопиющий. Пускай будет по-Вашему.

Comment: Здесь логично считать, что совсем не серия соревнований, а приз, не обязательно сосуд. А хотя бы и серия. Чемпионат (мира, области, района) - тоже серия соревнований, вы не будете требовать заглавной?!

Comment: "Чемпионат", да, обычно со строчной пишут.

Comment: Как вы мне надоели с этим кубком. Это обычный кубок. Награда. Как медаль, как орден. Заглавной не нужно. Можно еще сказать "победил на Кубке", но тоже не лучший выбор, но "выиграть Кубок" - это точно дурной тон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю вопрос, но смысл фраз понимаю, могут быть разные толкования слов "теоретически" и "практически".

"Теоретически дом уже построен, а практически до этого еще далеко" - ничто не мешает построить дом, все проблемы решены, надо только действовать. не самое удачное употребление, согласен. Теория противопоставляется практике почти как антагонизм.

Теоретически он уже стал обладателем кубка, а практически ему еще предстоит это доказать на последнем соревновании" - Здесь тоже имеется в виду теория, что ничто не мешает выиграть кубок, но для этого надо выступить удачно на последнем соревновании. Если это действительно какой-то "Кубок мира" или что-то подобное, то такое употребление противоречит сложившейся практике. Обычно под "теоретической победой" понимают ситуацию, когда догнать лидера уже невозможно при **любом** исходе оставшихся стартов.

"Теоретически ты прав, а практически - все может быть" - это в духе "гладко было на бумаге". Тут прослеживается неверие говорящего в теорию.

Comment: Да, интересно. Я только не совсем поняла, признаете это понимание возможным? Или их тут несколько, и неправильно только с кубком?

Answer (score 1):

Да, странное понимание взаимоотношения теории и практики.
тут надо понимать две вещи.

~1. То, что ***запрещает*** теория, не может быть сделано на практике. (иначе теория неверна, этот случай выносим за скобки).

~2. То, что ***разрешает*** теория, не обязательно может осуществиться на практике.

Оба эти утверждения считаю постулатами базового уровня, исходящими из смысла понятий "теория" и "практика". Когда эти вещи смешивают, возникают коллизии подобно вами приведенных. При этом вполне понятно, откуда они берутся. Во всех трех случаях имеется в виду разрешающая теория, т.е. постулат №2, это подход гуматитариев. А у физикков-математиков во главу угла стаится постулат №1 - то, что теория предписыают, тем самым **запрещая иное**.

Вот что касается спортивных комментаторов, то они по моим наблюдениям тяготеют к математическому пониманию подобных терминов (я часто слышал в их речи эти слов)Ю поэтому фраза про то, что обеспечено теорией надо еще доказывать на практике выглядит противоестественно, видимо её произнесший или написавший, принадлежал к редкому типу комментаторов-гуманитариев. И если две другие у меня вызывать лишь легкий скепсис, то история с кубком - серьезный протест.

Answer (score 0):

Оба эти слова - длинные, сухие, импортные, звучат немелодично, избегайте их по мере возможности.

Русское "На бумаге" часто гораздо точнее передаёт смысл, чем "теоретически". Например, в первом случае - "Теоретически дом уже построен..." - скорее всего можно заменить на "на бумаге", т.е. по отчётам.

"Теоретически ты прав, а практически - все может быть" - вполне грамотно, если речь идёт о соответствии каким-то правилам, представлениям, в т.ч. и теории.

"Теоретически он уже стал обладателем кубка"... - то же что и выше, если под "теорией" имеются в виду формальные правила соревнований. Например: он победил во всех заплывах (ждём результатов тестов на допинг). Иначе лучше сказать "кубок почти у него в руках" (если он победит в последнем турнире).

Comment: *Например: он победил во всех заплывах (ждём результатов тестов на допинг)* - только не это. )) Это как раз будет означать, что победил **практически**, а вот в теории - да, есть еще допинг-тест.

Comment: Это наверное один из интересных случаев когда "практически" и "теоретически" означают одно и то же, а разница возникает между "практически" и "на самом деле" :)

Comment: Нет, "теоретически" - это только в вашем понимании. Не думаю, что подобную ситуацию кто-то подобным образом охарактеризует эту ситуацию с допинг-тестом. Тут смысл другой. "Практически" должно означать, что иное маловероятно - и для практических нужд его (иное) можно не рассматривать. А "теоретически" - что иное не возможно в принципе. В какой другой сфере я бы еще согласился, но не в данном случае. Тут как бросание монетки. На ребро ***теоретически*** может встать, теории не противоречит, хотя практически же такое невозможно. А вот зависнуть в воздухе - не может теоретически.

Comment: По поводу "на самом деле" - ну тут еще можно согласиться, это можно понять как "практически", хотя тоже не главное значение, "на самом деле" - это презумптивное положение, близкое к "априори" и/или "апостериори", даже объединяющее в чем-то эти две посылки. Но это отдельный разговор, мы утонем, если будем его здесь вести.