# "Практически" в значении "почти"

Tags: стилистика, значение-слов

Является ли современной нормой употребление слова "практически" в значении "почти", "в основном", "по большей части"? В разговорном стиле, деловом?

Когда не стоит употреблять слово "практически" в значении "почти"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, является нормой. У слова "практически" два значения: 1 — на практике; 2 — по сути. У второго значения много синонимов: почти, в сущности, можно сказать, едва ли, чуть не, около и др.

[dic.academic.ru](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/133203/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8)
[synonymonline.ru](https://synonymonline.ru/%D0%9F/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/133203/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Я исправил ссылки по своему разумению. Правки Orient не понял.

Answer (score 1):

В значении "почти" никогда не стоит. Нет такого значения у "практически".

Есть значение, в чем-то подобное "почти", означающее, что для **практических целей**  что-то такое можно считать равным или соответствующим чему-то. Оно возможно. Но только оно.
*"Наше молоко практически неотличимо от натурального".*
Тут не просто "почти" — тут именно то, что на практике, хотя при желании отличить можно.

Остальные значения у "практически" противопоставляются "теоретически" и к "почти" не имеют ни малейшего отношения.

["Практически" и "теоретически" - значения](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422334)

Comment: У меня сложилось впечатление, что люди, когда хотят придать своей речи оттенок рассудительности, именно что используют слово "практически" в значении "почти". Это сплошь и рядом.